# sql backup job fails but still sends out success email

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008R2 Agent job to backup and shrink a database.  Every once in a while it fails with 'Cannot shrink log file 2 (insert database name here_log) because the logical log file located at the end of the file is in use. [SQLSTATE 01000]' but it still sends out an email saying it has succeeded.  In the Job properties, the e-mail is set to 'When the job completes'.  The On success action is set to 'Go to the next step' and the On failure action is 'Quit the job reporting failure'.  Was not sure if it is something with this error as other errors report failures or what is going on.  Any in site would be great.

Comment: Also, there are two databases to backup and the job never moves onto the second database.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have selected the option `when the job completes` and it so rightly sends an email when the job completes regardless of whether it fails or successfully completes.

For your Alters you need to set is to `When the Job fails`

[image]

It is very important that you set your alerts about things that you really care and needs your attention. When a job completes of successfully completes, it doesnt really need much of a attention but if something is failing it does need to be looked at and it is important that you know about.

So make sure you only set the alerts that you really care about otherwise you will be getting bombarded with emails left right center and you most probably will miss that one important alert about that failed job.

Comment: I have several other instances that have the same settings and sends out e-mail when there is a failure and when there is success.

Comment: What is then the difference between when the job succeeds and the job completes?